# Using Protractor with Firefox or IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

Protractor works fine with Chrome, but I cannot get it to start up Firefox or Internet Explorer.

- Windows 7
- Node v6.9.1

Snippet from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ....
    "webdriver-manager-update": "webdriver-manager update --ie",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.conf.js",
    ...
},
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    ...
}
```

`protractor.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
      browserName: "firefox" // or "internet explorer"
    },
    specs: ["target/e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.js"]
};
```

After running `npm run webdriver-manager-update`, `<project-home>\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\` contains the files `chromedriver_2.28.exe`, `geckodriver-v0.15.0.exe` and `IEDriverServer3.3.0.exe`.

When running `npm run protractor`, I get an error:

```
[12:29:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:29:45] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:29:46] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.213.25:62661/wd/hub
[12:29:46] E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property
```

(for IE, it refers to the `webdriver.ie.driver` system property)

After lots of googling, I tried the following fixes:

a) Add `<project-home>\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\` to the system environment variable `Path`. This seems to make no difference.

b) Add the following line to `protractor.conf.js`:

```
seleniumArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=<project-home>\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.15.0.exe"],
```

Now `npm run protractor` yields:

```
[12:40:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:40:35] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:40:35] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at Error (native)
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (<project-home>\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:252:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
[12:40:35] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

(analoguous behavior with IE)

My search results suggest I am not the only one having this problem, but unfortunately, I did not discover a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in an [answer by Nick Tomlin](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4137#issuecomment-284577227):

Its is not `seleniumArgs` you need to set, but `localSeleniumStandaloneOpts.jvmArgs`. So, in `protractor.conf.js`, write:

```
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=<project-home>\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.15.0.exe"]
  },
```

(analoguous for IE)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a `localSeleniumStandaloneOpts`. The local driver option lets you start the selenium standalone server before the Protractor test, run the test, and finally takes down the server.

Another way you could do this is with `webdriver-manager start --ie` and the `seleniumAddress` in your configuration file. In your configuration file, you will set `seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"`.

A quick note about Firefox. Make sure that you are running the latest gecko driver and Firefox versions. If the Firefox tests are not running properly, look at the [gecko driver github issues page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues).

Another note about Internet Explorer. You should use IE11 and the 32-bit driver version. If you look at the [Protractor issues page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues), iedriver has been identified to have issues. I assume that these issues will not be fixed.

Comment: I can confirm the other way works. One must not forget to run the global `webdriver-manager update --ie` if one wants to run the global `webdriver-manager start --ie`.